# RHEL 6.9 HA clustering issue with one node completely down

Tags: rhel, storage, cluster, multipath-storage

I have two node servers with SAN storage.
Each node have RHEL 6.9 with HA and the partition are mapped from the storage using fiber cables with clustered resources.

The thing is when the two nodes are working everything is fine. When one node is completely removed and the other node rebooted the clustered service will not work if there is no ping to the other node with the managment port.

Then after starting the second node the cluster start ok.

Fencing are configured ok.

Server model `Dell emc R640`

Storage `Dell Me4012`

What is this? Misconfiguration??

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean the clustered service does not work? What is the filesystem that you're using for this cluster solution? What is the status of clvmd (if this is used)? The cluster quorum should have a fence device. Without a fence device, you could end up with split-brain functionality and corrupted data (depending on your setup). What is the status of the filesystem mount What is the status of clvmd? Have you tried to start all the services you need manually? clustat ?

Comment: I mean there is clustered resources that mount file system partition as ext4 form the storage when the cluster start.. The status of clvmd is running for both nodes but when one node down completely form the power and you reboot the other node the clvmd will not start on boot.. Showing time out.. Quorum and fencing are configured properly.. And yes i have tried to start rgmanager but it's not starting and clustat are not showing the resources required.. Note that in this resources there is a file system mounting and virtual ip for database as required and script for application.

Comment: Once you start the other node and you do network restart on the other node.. Everything start normal.

Comment: Also mounting the file systems partitions form the storage works but cluster will not work.

Comment: Ok , if clvmd does not start then you have an issue with cman. service cman status / systemctl status cman. Anything specific in /var/log/messages? You have cman > clvmd > GFS? any fence device?

Comment: check ccsd, fenced and groupd services status as well.

Comment: Cman will start at boot but clvmd not. Showing tcp communication then time out.. Like its looking for the other node.. Logs will show python: request time out.. Later when we configure one file system as gfs2 it wiil not mount in this situation with one node.. Only two nodes. Note. after reboot with one node down completely. It will stuck at booting gfs2 partition.

Comment: still no information on the fence device

Comment: are you using pacemakerd?

Comment: Fencing devices are idrac and configured fenc instance on the two nodes

Comment: Luci and ricci are configured also

Comment: No im not using pacemakerd

Comment: I haven't worked with Conga, nor ricci/luci so I can't be of further help.

Comment: Reconfigure quorum votes appropriately so that one node will be available as a Cluster member even though other node is inaccessible. Are you using heuristics?

Comment: GFS2 file systems placed in `/etc/fstab` will not mount automatically on boot via the same mechanisms that mount other file systems; rather, these file systems will only be mounted by the `gfs2` startup service in RHEL 5 or 6, and will not be mounted at all on boot and must be configured to mount via other means. In RHEL 5 and 6 with `rgmanager`, a `clusterfs` resource can mount GFS2 file systems as part of a service.